# Excel conditional formatting based on cell content

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

I am trying to write a conditional formatting formula for the rule "if the first cell of this row is NOT empty AND the current cell IS empty".

Basically I am trying to bring attention when a user has forgotten to enter a value in a cell.

The formula I came up with was:

```
="NOT(isblank($A1)) AND isblank(A1)"
```

Please provide an explanation why my formula is wrong, not just the correct formula =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical "AND" is not an operator in Excel, it is just another function.  Excel doesn't know how to evaluate =FUNCA() AND FUNCB().  Instead, wrap the two functions inside the AND function:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($A8)), ISBLANK(M8))
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, I knew it would be something simple!